Gnome shell extension with custom shortcut
I am trying to create an extension for gnome (following partially the documentation in https://gjs.guide/ and in https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/libadwaita/doc/1-latest/index.html). I'm targeting recent versions of Gnome (let say 47 for now).
I can't figure out how to create a custom keyboard shortcut for the extension.
I would like to have, in the preference page of the extension, a row where the user can change the shortcut. Or some alternative way to let the user change the shortcut.
I'm searching at the code needed in the files extension.js, pref.js.

you might stand a better chance of getting an answer to your question on GNOME Discourse. This doesn't appear to be Ubuntu specific.
